# How do I display square bracketed followed by round bracketed text in HTML without it being registered as a hyperlink?

Tags: html, formatting, parentheses, square-bracket

I have an example that I am trying to write out in another forum, but I believe HTML formatting is registering my example as hyperlinks. Here is what I am trying to write out:

`[who is](who_is_was) [the](our_the) [project engineer](requested_info) [for](of_on_for) [12345](project_number)`

Because there are no spaces between the [square bracketed text] and the (rounded bracketed text) the text is being registered as a hyperlink. The example ends up looking like this:

`who is the project engineer for 12345`

How to I prevent this?

Comment: That syntax is specific to [Markdown hyperlinks](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links) and you can avoid it by escaping any of the brackets with the backspace character like so: `\[ ... ]( ... )`. \[Markdown hyperlinks](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links)

Comment: Escape it with a backslash `\\`